# Check Three Dom Elements to See if they are empty or not and return detailed result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking three elements on the DOM to see if they are empty or not so that I can run only the Ajax calls that I should run and save on overall bandwidth. The code works but it "smells bad". Here is my source.

```javascript
const processValues = (area, city, text) => {
    if (area.val() && city.val() && text.val()) {
        return 'all';
    } else if (area.val() && city.val() && !text.val()) {
        return 'areaCity';
    } else if (area.val() && !city.val() && text.val()) {
        return 'areaText';
    } else if (area.val() && !city.val() && !text.val()) {
        return 'city';
    } else if (!area.val() && city.val() && text.val()) {
        return 'cityText';
    } else if (!area.val() && !city.val() && text.val()) {
        return 'text';
    } else if (!area.val() && city.val() && !text.val()) {
        return 'city';
    } else {
        return 'none';
    }
};
```

I will be repeating this check in a few methods and I will be using a switch statement in those methods with the returned string values. If there is a better way to do this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with some friends, this is seen as the best solution. One adjustment to the return values was required however; change the casing from camel case to title case. I am also using constants to make sure that return values can be consistently used properly.

````javascript
/**
 * Check the three dom elements to see if they are empty or not and return detailed result.
 * @param {jQuery|HTMLElement} area Area input field.
 * @param {jQuery|HTMLElement} city City input field.
 * @param {jQuery|HTMLElement} text Text input field.
 * @return {string} Detailed result of which input fields are empty.
 * If all are filled, returns "all".
 * If none are filled, returns empty string.
 */
export const processValues = (area, city, text) => {
    const a = (area.val()) ? 'Area' : '';
    const c = (city.val()) ? 'City' : '';
    const t = (text.val()) ? 'Text' : '';
    if (a !== "" && c !== "" && t !== "") {
        return "all";
    } else {
        return a + c + t;
    }
};

export const ALL = "all";
export const AREA_CITY = "AreaCity";
export const AREA_TEXT = "AreaText";
export const AREA = "Area";
export const CITY_TEXT = "CityText";
export const CITY = "City";
export const TEXT = "Text";
```
````

Comment: Please try to use either `""` or `''` at all occurrences. Please also try to use better naming than `a`, `c`, `t`. Why do you need to `export` these constants? Where is `none`?